# Danger/a danger (noncountable)

Tags: meaning

1. You are in a danger.
2. You are in danger.

Of what context does each one describe? What kind of danger is uncountable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would not say

> You are in a danger

You second formulation is the normal use of this noun

> You are in danger

We do use the countable form when referring to a specific danger or dangers

> These steps are uneven, there is a danger of falling
>
> The many dangers of smoking

Comment: I would not say, "You are in a danger," but I might very well say, "You are in a dangerous situation."

Comment: Thank you. What if you see a mud pond. Would you say 1. There is a danger(refering to the pond), or 2. There is danger(still refering the pond)?

Comment: @JoeKim In AmE we would say: *That pond is dangerous*, or *That pond is/poses a real danger*, but we would rarely if ever say *There is a danger*.

Comment: I agree with Alan that we would not in isolation say "There is a danger" but we do say "There is a danger of drowning". http://www.thesignshed.co.uk/danger-of-drowning-warning-sign-11530-p.asp